# Countdown Timer Skipping Time in C#

Tags: c#, string, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I Have This in C#

```
private void counter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", Hour) + ":" + String.Format("{0:00}", Minute) + ":" + String.Format("{0:00}", Second);
        if (Second != 00)
        {
            Second = Second - 1;
        }
        else if (Minute != 00)
        {
            Minute = Minute - 1;
            Second = 59;
        }
        else if (Hour != 00)
        {
            Hour = Hour - 1;
            Minute = 59;
        }
        else
        {
            counter.Stop();
            Time.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Which Does work but when it gets to minus an hour to add to minutes, it goes from 00 minutes to 58 minutes instead of 59

EG.

```
From: 001:00:00
To:   000:58:59
```

And is there a better way to make a countdown timer that does something when it hits 000:00:00???

Comment: I would not use timer for this, or not this way. I would use DateTime for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well let's see what happens when the time is `10:00:00`.

1. Subtract one hour: `09:00:00`.
2. Set minutes to 59: `09:59:00`.

If you notice the time is off by one minute (`10:00:00 - 09:59:00 = 00:01:00`).  The solution is to set the seconds to 59 also.  So now our code is.

```
// ...
else if (Hour != 00)
{
    Hour = Hour - 1;
    Minute = 59;
    Second = 59;
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard .Net classes for subtracting time:

```
private TimeSpan timeSpan;
private TimeSpan oneSecond = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Time.Text = timeSpan.ToString();

    if (timeSpan == TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        Time.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        timer.Stop();
        return;
    }

    timeSpan -= oneSecond;
}
```

Initialize timespan when you starting your timer (I used System.Timers.Timer):

```
timeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `Second` to `59`. Else, once the timer ticks again, it immediately switches to `else if (Minute != 00)` and decrements `Minute` (which is already `59`) by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start;
DateTime final;

private void start()
{
    start = DateTime.Now;
    final = start + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
}

private void counter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start = DateTime.Now;
    Time.Text = (final-start).Hours.ToString() + ":" + (final-start).Minutes.ToString() + ":" + (final-start).Seconds.ToString();    
    if (final == start)
    {
        //final code
    }        
}
```

Comment: Timespans would be a better choice as you're not interested in the date part. final.addSeconds(-1).ToString() would be better than (final-start) 3 times as that could mean you skip intervals as time is always advancing.

Comment: Yep that is true, but still better as the original solution I believe

Comment: Actually it isn't. Just looked again and every counter tick will just output 1:00:00 as nothing is being decremented on each counter tick. your final code will never be reached as final can never equal start.

Comment: :D Oops, really, did not notice that, repaired